# MYSQL to order before grouping by

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following:

```
user_id   date_created   project_id
3         10/10/2013     1
3         09/10/2013     1
5         10/10/2013     1
8         10/10/2013     1
10        10/10/2013     1
3         08/10/2013     1
```

The end result i want is:

```
user_id   date_created   project_id
3         10/10/2013     1
5         10/10/2013     1
8         10/10/2013     1
10        10/10/2013     1
```

**Context:**

I have this thing called an influence, and a user can have many influences for a project.
I want to get a list of the latest influence from a user on a project.

I have tried:

```
select * from influences 
where project_id = 1 
group by user_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

but of course this ignores first ordering by user created at, and then ordering the full list. It simply just squishes the users together and orders the end list

---

**THE LARAVEL - Eloquent FOR THE ANSWER PROVIDED IS THIS:**

```
return Influence::select( "user_id",  "influence", DB::raw( "MAX(created_at) as created_at" ) )
                ->where( "project_id", "=", $projectID )
                ->groupBy( "user_id", "project_id" )->get();
```

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under the mysql tag. Just sayin'

Comment: And yet, I didn't find it when searching over and over.

Comment: This is the way `GROUP BY` works. Use the MAX() aggregate value to get the most recent `date_created`.

Comment: Are there other columns in table `influence`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to order before `group by`, because given the structure of your query, it won't necessary do what you want.

If you want the most recently created influence, then get it explicitly:

```
select i.*
from influences i join
     (select user_id, max(created_at) as maxca
      from influences i
      where project_id = 1
      group by user_id
     ) iu
     on iu.user_id = i.user_id and iu.maxca = i.created_at
where i.project_id = 1;
```

Your intention is to use a MySQL extension that the documentation *explicitly* warns against using.  You want to include columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  As the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) says:

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each
>   group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

Comment: Cheers man! I actually didn't realise you would do a select on a join... Very helpful and it works great!

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  This appears to be a correct answer.

Comment: I am the downvoter. Is there a reason for sub-queries?

Comment: @axiac . . . What do you mean?  You need the subquery to get the most recent `created_at` date for each user.  This allows the query to pull all the columns from `influences`.

Comment: In the example code, all the columns are `user_id` (included in `GROUP BY`), `project_id` (always `1`, filtered in the `WHERE` clause) and `MAX(created_at)`. A simple `SELECT` with `GROUP BY` is enough. If there are other fields (the OP didn't mention them yet) then the query is different but it still doesn't need inner queries (and even `GROUP BY` becomes useless).

Comment: @axiac . . . This is a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT user_id, project_id, MAX(date_created) as latest
FROM influences
WHERE project_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id, project_id
```

How it works: MySQL selects all the rows that match the `WHERE` conditions and sorts them by `user_id` then, for each `user_id` by `project_id`. From each set of rows having the same `user_id` and `project_id` it will produce a single row in the final result set.

You can use in the `SELECT` clause the columns used in the `GROUP BY` clause (`user_id` and `project_id`); their values are unambiguous: all the rows from each group have the same `user_id` and `project_id`.

You can also use [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html). Each of them uses one column from all the rows in the group to compute a single value. The most recent `created_at` is, of course, `MAX(created_at)`.

If you select a column that is neither included in the `GROUP BY` clause, nor passed to an aggregate function (like `created_at` you have in your query), MySQL has no hint how to compute that value. The standard `SQL` forbids it (the query is not valid) but MySQL [allows it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). It will simply pick a value from that column but there is no way to make it pick it from a specific row because this is, in fact, undefined behaviour.

You can omit the `project_id` from the `GROUP BY` clause because the `WHERE` clause will make all the rows having the same `project_id`. This will coincidentally make the result correct even if `project_id` does not appear in a `GROUP BY` clause and it's not computed using an aggregate function.

I recommend you to keep `project_id` into the `GROUP BY` clause. It doesn't affect the result or the query speed and it allows you to loose the filtering conditions (f.e. use `WHERE project_id IN (1, 2)`) always get the correct result (this doesn't happen if you remove it from `GROUP BY`).

Comment: This answer only handles the columns displayed in the example code from the question. If the table `influences` contains other columns (not displayed here) then this answer doesn't work. The correct answer in that case can be found on the dozens of similar questions on SO.

Comment: I've used your solution instead, it's quite a bit faster.

Comment: I've just realised that the outcome isn't correct. It shuffles the columns around and it's difficult to tell why... however the other one definitely works... If you include the SELECT to have "influence" the influence is being assigned to the wrong user

Comment: As I said in my previous comment on this answer, it works only if the table contains just the three columns exposed in the question. It also provides correct results if any other columns that are selected in the database have the same value on all the rows that have the same `user_id`.

Comment: If you need to select more columns then you need a different query. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183964/sql-sorting-does-not-follow-group-by-statement-always-uses-primary-key/27184343#27184343), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801243/how-to-select-a-row-with-maximum-value-for-a-column-in-mysql/27801835#27801835) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql/27802817#27802817) on questions similar with yours. Add the `WHERE product_id = 1` condition to them.